# Win32 Api - a more dialog-based program

Tags: winapi, win32-process

So , I have a textbox(in win32) that I made.

```
    TextBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,"EDIT", "Hello you name is: ",
                             WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,
                             140,50,500, 250,
                             hwnd, NULL, NULL , NULL);
```

My question is: How can I get to add multiple text in the "textbox"

My program is mostly made out of questions that i ask and the user responds to it.

Question two: How can I make this "dialog" between the user and the computer.

Last, but not least, I've made these buttons:

```
    Submit = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Submit", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                          450,320,80,20,
                          hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);




    SubmitQuestion = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Inregistreaza raspuns", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                                  310,350,150,26,
                                  hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);



    Next =  CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Next", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                         250,320, 80, 20,
                         hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL , NULL);
```

Submit works, but when I press next nothing happens. How can the user by clicking "NEXT" can go to the next question and also when he presses submit his answer to be registered?

And also , how by SendMessage , classes are included (calling functions ) ---> I have a method of "questions" (8) and i don't know how to call it in order to work with the textbox and win32 syntax.

Comment: The intent of this Stack's network of websites is that separate questions be asked separately. Try to resolve one thing at a time.

Comment: You can continue to use the very basic Win32 API, and create another window for the textbox (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598067/how-to-create-a-windows-style-textbox-in-a-c-win32-application ).  From your description, you may find using MFC much easier, and there are many tutorials available online for building simple, dialog-based applications that sound like what you want to achieve, e.g. http://depts.washington.edu/cmmr/biga/chapter_tutorials/1.C++_MFC_D3DOGL/1.StepByStepGuide/index.html

Comment: Il try to look over MFC.Till then, I hope I'll solve this matter.

Comment: The buttons `SubmitQuestion` and `Next` share the same ID. Plus, using the IDs `IDOK` (1) and `IDCANCEL` (2) for your own buttons is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your editbox needs to have a unique ID (passed in the hMenu parameter).  If you intend for the editbox to display more than one line of text it also needs to have ES_MULTILINE style.

Each of your buttons also needs to have a unique ID.

Your other questions are not clear.