# What changes have to be done to make this Windows textbox from 2011, work now, in 2019?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019

What changes have to be done to make this Windows textbox from 2011, work now, in 2019?

I tried compiling the code in [this question from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598067/how-to-create-a-windows-style-textbox-in-a-c-win32-application) about making a C++ Textbox...

```
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR nCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    LPTSTR windowClass = TEXT("WinApp");
    LPTSTR windowTitle = TEXT("Windows Application");
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = windowClass;
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("RegisterClassEx Failed!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    HWND hWnd;

    if (!(hWnd = CreateWindow(windowClass, windowTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL)))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("CreateWindow Failed!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    HWND hWndEdit = CreateWindow(TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("test"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 100, 20, 140, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

But trying to build it in Visual Studio 2019, I get errors about being unable to convert a "t_char" to a "LPTSTR".

So, how do I update the code to work? And is it possible without Including any other files?

Comment: Old code might require Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > Conformance Mode = "No" to still compile cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LPCTSTR` instead of `LPTSTR`:

```cpp
LPCTSTR windowClass = TEXT("WinApp");
LPCTSTR windowTitle = TEXT("Windows Application");
```

`LPTSTR` is `TCHAR *`

`LPCTSTR` is `const TCHAR *`

`TEXT("literal")` produces a `const TCHAR []`.

A string literal is const data. Since C++11, you can no longer assign a string literal to a pointer-to-non-const.

Comment: Do I have to Include something beyond Windows.h? 'Cause my Visual Studio isn't registering LPTCSTR as something defined.

Comment: It's `LPCTSTR` (or, y'know, `wchar_t const *`).

Comment: @Malandy my bad, I had the `C` in the wrong position. I have fixed it

Comment: @quent `TCHAR const*`, as `TCHAR` can be different types depending on build settings.

Comment: @Yakk the old ASCII API is all kinds of broken though, so it's mostly best left forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

Get out of the TCHAR business entirely.  Those TEXT macros are for cross-compiling with code meant to run on Windows 9x.

Changes these lines:

```
LPTSTR windowClass = TEXT("WinApp");
LPTSTR windowTitle = TEXT("Windows Application");
```

To this:

```
LPCWSTR windowClass = L"WinApp";
LPCWSTR windowTitle = L"Windows Application";
```

And then all subsequent usages of TEXT macros like in the following:

```
MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("RegisterClassEx Failed!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
```

To just be wide strings:

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"RegisterClassEx Failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
```

Comment: I give people the answers they need.  Not always the answers they want.

Comment: Although this answer contains technically correct information, it does not try to explain why the OP's code fails to compile, let alone explain what the actual fix is. Also, the changes described require the project to be set to use the Unicode character set since the code is still calling `TCHAR`-based function macros with non-`TCHAR`-based data. To avoid that, it would need to call the Wide functions directly, ie `MessageBoxW(NULL, L"...",...)`, etc

Comment: Why use `LPCWSTR` alphabet soup?  Also, MBCS (where TCHAR is 8 buts) code can run on modern windows OS's; not wise, but possible.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont in general, when using a given API, you should use the types defined by that API. Sure, you could use base language types directly, but if/when the API changes in the future, it is more work to update your code to match the changes.

Comment: @remy I argue use `TCHAR const*`.  `TCHAR` is 9999x more likely to chamge back to 8 bit than `LPCWSTR` to be anything but `WCHAR const*`, and neither are very likely.