# How to make a MessageBox with a box to type text in Eclipse C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, winapi, messagebox

I am currently looking for a way to type a text into a messagebox and then get it back as a String, but I have no idea if this is even possible in Eclipse C++, I'm not that familiar with c++. This is the code that i have at the moment:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include "Helloworldschrijver.hpp"

using namespace std;


int starting text () {

    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Test 1",
            "Insert Time",
            MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `MessageBoxA` is a pretty simple function that can only show text and some buttons such as OK, Cancel etc. You need to make your own dialog. BTW this question is unrelated to Eclipse.

Comment: What do you mean with Eclipse C++? Do you mean Eclipse CDT? That's an IDE without compiler.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I am working in the Eclipse IDE with c++, i was not sure if knowing what IDE i was using is necessary for the question.

Comment: You need to learn windows programming. Refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598067/how-to-create-a-windows-style-textbox-in-a-c-win32-application), it create a textEdit in window, then you can type information into it. Use [`GetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) to get the information which you need to add. There is a long way to go...

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently looking for a way to type a text into a messagebox and then get it back as a String

The Windows API does not have a single function for the purpose of prompting the user for text input, like it does for displaying a message box.  So you will have to create your own UI dialog that has an edit field on it.  Which means you will have to learn Win32 UI programming.  Or else install and use a 3rd party UI framework that handles the details for you.